# set nslocale for number part of nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way to set locale on number part of string ?

like if nsstring is like this :  "**0.510.220**"  it shows this inside

uilabel view : "**۰.۵۱۰.۲۲۰**"

i know i can change the nslocale with this if number are valid :

```
NSDecimalNumber *someNumber = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"123"];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *gbLocale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"ar"] autorelease];
[formatter setLocale:gbLocale];
```

but how can i make that happen on full nsstring text? like number inside

string.also im want to make this happen on +7.0 sdk.

Comment: you want to convert the string into arabic ?

Comment: i want to convert the number inside the string to arabic nslocale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because what you want is not something that a locale does. "۰.۵۱۰.۲۲۰" is not "0.510.220" in a different locale, it's just simply a different string.

Strings don't have locales. They consist of characters. A string with the characters "0.510.220" has those characters, not others. The Arabic digits are different characters and so you'd need a string with different content.

An `NSNumberFormatter` is not applying a locale to a string. It's applying a locale to the conversion from a number to a string. That's completely different from what you seem to want.

You could try to parse your string to find a substring that appears to be a number, convert that substring to an actual number using one `NSNumberFormatter` in one locale, convert the resulting number back to a string using a second `NSNumberFormatter` in a different locale, and construct a new string by replacing the original substring with the new string.